# Is it possible to add a parameter to the Firebase default 'session_start' event?

Tags: firebase, firebase-analytics

The title is the content. I want to add a parameter to the `session_start` event.

[The document](https://support.google.com/firebase/answer/7061705?hl=en) says that there is no parameter for the `session_start` event, but no information about the custom parameter.

Is it possible to add a parameter to the `session_start` event? Is it impossible to add a parameter to all the Firebase default event?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's no way to add a custom parameter to the session_start event, or to any other automatically collected event, since parameters are added when you call logEvent and your app doesn't call logEvent for automatically collected events.  Depending on the information you wanted to add to the session_start event, there may be other ways of gathering that information.

Comment: New to Firebase Analytics and wanting to record my users' preferred font size I was hoping I could stick that in here. I could track % of time in app used by people preferring different fonts sizes I'm struggling a big to find the perfect spot for it. Right now it's in the app open event.

Comment: This is a user preference; Google Analytics for Firebase might not be the best way to store or record it. If you just want to store it on the local device you could use [shared preferences](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences). Since preferred font size for a single user is likely to be different for each device, this is probably the best approach.  If you want to do statistical analysis on the preferred font sizes of all your users you could report it in a [user property](https://firebase.google.com/docs/analytics/user-properties?platform=android).