# Is it possible to add a custom parameter to an in-built Firebase event like in_app_purchase

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-analytics

I can see how to set up this parameter in the Console (vertical ellipsis, then "Edit Parameter Reporting), but it's unclear to me how I would set this parameter value within my iOS app. My goal essentially is to associate some data with each in app purchase, but creating a new event for that (when one already exists) seems like a hack.

Comment: This seems to not be possible. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50968483/is-it-possible-to-add-a-parameter-to-the-firebase-default-session-start-event, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53338565/how-to-send-custom-parameter-along-with-reserve-event-to-firebase-analytics/53339477#53339477